# google+ login - how to hide the clientid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oauth

I am trying to get a simple google+ login working. I was able to get the javascript example working but that means I have to put my clientId on the same page which will be visible in source.
I was doing some research and found so far that it may be possible to hide that code using a span/ div/ form-group?
Not sure how to go about that. Including the details in css will still make the details accessible.

```
<div id="gConnect">
<button class="g-signin"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
    data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
    data-clientId="xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    data-callback="onSignInCallback"
    data-theme="dark"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin">
</button>
```

I plan to add facebook etc. to the project too so looking to find a generic way.

Comment: you can put script in seperate js file

Comment: you mean the entire code from `<div` onwards? Or you mean declare span in another js file and refer it?

Comment: well i think there is no issue if your cient id is visible,, facebook apps also have client id visible in the request url in query string

Comment: I thought so too, then when I looked at SO source, didn't find any app id/ client id visible. They seem to be using a span approach. Haven't figured out how to do that. That looks more professional

Answer (score 0):

See related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34833820/do-we-need-to-hide-the-google-oauth-client-id). TLDR - you don't need to hide your client ID provided you have set up your server-side restrictions correctly.