# Do we need to hide the google oauth client id?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

everyone. I'm recently learning OAuth authentication. I'm playing around with google's oauth api. In the tutorial for [Google Sign-In for server-side apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow), in the third step - Initialize the GoogleAuth object, you need to provide the client id to initialize the GoogleAuth object. I'm just wondering if we need to keep the client id secret because right now anyone can find out what the client id is by looking into the javascript.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need to hide the client ID, provided that you restricted access to specific JavaScript origins and redirect URI's on the server side. See more details on [this Quora thread](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-OK-to-expose-the-OAuth-client-ID-and-use-it-as-an-API-key) or [this IETF thread](http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/oauth/current/msg08181.html).

Answer (score 0):

here is how it looks like, lets assume the intruder have that `client_id` but there is a guard checking like,

"okay you got the key, but let me see if you are part of the whitelist"

that is why we have `javascript origin`, it should be these 2 condition satisfied able to have an access,

Conditions

- has `client_id`
- is part of `javascript origin`

but not doesn't mean you totally want to expose it that it can easy to search or what, still do a handy job in order not easily to see it